# Decimal without tofixed

Tags: javascript

Hi i need to format my number for prevent many decimal

I need like

```
1.123 its good

1.12345678 its good too

1.12345678900001 format to 1.12345678 with maximum 8 decimal
```

Now i use just a function for add comma but not work with decimal

```
function commas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just replace `x[1]` with `x[1].substr(0, 8)`?

Comment: This actually seems like two questions - the first question being 'how do I restrict my number to 8 d.p.' and the second being 'how do I comma separate a number'

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this jQuery plugin. You can use this plugin to format the text node, input node's value as you want.

Also you can reference the format method if you don't want to use this plugin.

[jQuery-formatmoney](https://github.com/sgyyz/jquery-formatmoney)

You can reference the `format` method in this plugin.

The main format regular expression is:

```
integerPart = integerPart.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, options.thousands);
```

Comment: *" Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Comment: reference the format regular expression. you can use this regular expression to format your integer part and decimal part. then add them together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does the trick:

```
function commas(nStr,maxDecimals){
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    x1 = x1.replace('.',','); //replace . into ,
    x2 = x2.substr(0, maxDecimals) ; //select the max amount of decimals
    return x1 + x2;
}
```